# setState() is not working in async calls in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to read a json file named `mood.json` and parse it to a list named "data", but when I run `setState()`, the `data` never changed, any help about this problem? The code looks like this:

```
class DisplayPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
  _DisplayPageState createState() => new _DisplayPageState();
}

class _DisplayPageState extends State<DisplayPage> {
  List _data = [];
  Directory dir;
  File jsonFile;
  String jsonPath;

    Future getData() async {
    dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    jsonPath = dir.path + "/" + "mood.json";
    jsonFile = new File(jsonPath);
    setState(() {
       _data = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    print(_data.length);
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new  Text('Mood')
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
          child: new Text(_data[index]["title"]),
          );
          },),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `setState`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: How do you use your state?

Comment: I reedited the question, sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Phuc Tran I want to use the `_data` list to build a listview widget, but the parsed  `_data` doesn't get passed to the state.

Comment: What file contains above code? When you add `print(_data);` after `_data = ...;` is the expected data printed?

Comment: The file contains a simple  json file in the code listed above. When I add `print(_data)` after `_data = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());`  , the contents in `_data` got printed out, but not working in the listview widget.

Comment: Does `lib/main.dart` contain any imports that don't start with `import 'package:...` or `import 'dart:...`? Also please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The outputs of `flutter doctor` don't have any warnings. I finally  found out the problem originates from incorrect json file format. Anyway, I really appreciate your tips and suggestions!

Answer (score 11):

I think your problem may be something else; I took your code and changed the network call to just wait 5 seconds and then return some dummy data and it worked fine.

```
Future getData() async {
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  setState(() {
    _data = [
      {"title": "one"},
      {"title": "two"},
    ];
  });
}
```

You should put a breakpoint inside your `setState` call to ensure it's actually being called and that the data being assigned to `_data` is as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307118/17218862), use

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(...));
```

instead of just

```
setState(...)
```

Comment: It worked, but could you explain how it works, please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "async" outside "setState" method.

**Note:** Use "await" for waitting for the response.

```
     Future getData() async {        
        dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        jsonPath = dir.path + "/" + "mood.json";
        jsonFile = new File(jsonPath);
        
        //Use async outside
        var json = await json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
        
        //Change values on setState
        setState(() {
           _data = json;
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT*
Sorry i was wrong, you can call async method from initState(), just call it without await

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /// getData(); /// this is an async method, and it's return a future. 
    /// you can use await instead so the code bellow getData() method execution 
    /// will be waiting for it to complete first.
    /// Here it is :
    getData(); 
    print(_data.length); /// This print now will waiting until the getData completed
}
```

here is some references : https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await

Comment: You cant call `getData` with `await`. `initState` would need to be async for that

Comment: Oh yes you are right thank you @MohitC, don't forget to add `Future<void> initState() async {}`

Comment: Yeah I dont think `initState` can be async mate

Comment: ah sorry for the confusion, btw you can just remove the `await getData()` and call it `getData()` instead. more check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764400/state-initstate-must-be-a-void-method-without-an-async-keyword