# State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword

Tags: flutter, dart

[![State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.
how can i solve this probelms][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43DSK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43DSK.png)

[image: how to solve this problem]

```
@override
  Future<void> initState() async {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _current_location();
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/fff.png').then((onValue) {
      pinLocationIcon = onValue;
    });
    //createCustomMarker(context);

   // final Marker marker = Marker(icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon));
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    ref.child('users').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      print(values.toString());
      values.forEach((k, v) {
        allMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(k),
          draggable: false,
          icon: pinLocationIcon,
          position: LatLng(v["latitude"], v["longitude"]),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: v["name"]),
          onTap: () {
            _onMarkerTapped(v["name"]);
          },
        ),);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Probably you are trying to run an async function(a http request with await probably?) in initstate which you can't do this directly. If you send your code we can help more.

Comment: Create a separate async function returning Future and then call that function inside initState.

Comment: the question its updated

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`initState` *must* be a method which takes no parameters and returns `void`. This is because it overrides the method of the same name in the superclass (`State<StatefulWidgetType>`). As such, this limitation is a contract that is fixed and binding; you cannot change it.

Of course, this also means that `initState` cannot be marked as `async`. This is because any method marked as `async` will implicitly return a `Future`, but if the method returns anything, it cannot have a return type of `void` which breaks the override contract.

If you need to call an `async` method from within `initState`, you can do so simply by not `await`ing it:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  doSomeAsyncStuff();
}

Future<void> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
  ...
}
```

If, however, you need the data from the `async` method for your widget, you cannot simply wait for the `Future` to return before you build the widget. Flutter does not allow this, because there is no telling how long it will take for the `Future` to return, and stalling the widget building until then could potentially block your entire app.

Instead, you need to have your widget build normally and then have a way to notify your widget to update when the `Future` has returned. This is most easily done with a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: doSomeAsyncStuff(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        // Future hasn't finished yet, return a placeholder
        return Text('Loading');
      }
      return Text('Loading Complete: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  );
}
```

*(Notice how instead of calling the `async` method from `initState`, I am calling it from the `FutureBuilder` during the build process.)*

---

EDIT: As pointed out, this approach only works in OP's situation where the awaited future will always eventually return a value. This is not always the case - sometimes the future doesn't return a value at all and is just a long-running process. Sometimes the future might return null instead of concrete data. And sometimes the future may result in an error instead of completing successfully. In any of these cases, `snapshot.data` will be null after the future completes, in which case `snapshot.hasData` will always be false.

In these situations, instead of depending on `snapshot.hasData` to wait for data to appear, you can use `snapshot.connectionState` to monitor the state of the future itself:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FutureBuilder(
   future: doSomeAsyncStuff(),
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
       // Future hasn't finished yet, return a placeholder
       return Text('Loading');
     }
     return Text('Loading Complete');
   }
 );
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I suppose the latter is better practice, than a fire-and-forget future? By the way, there's an extra dot in your last snippet (third last line).

Comment: I'm a newbie. But according to my practice, use `snapshot.connectionState = ConnectionState.done` works, cause snapshot.hasData seems always false to me.

Comment: @Vincent `snapshot.hasData` will be true when `snapshot.data` is not null. If the future you are waiting on doesn't actually return anything or has a chance of returning null, then `snapshot.hasData` can be false even after the future completes, in which case you should use `snapshot.connectionState` instead.

Comment: @Abion47 Can I safely use: `doSomeAsyncStuff().then((result) => //use result);`  in `initState()`?

Comment: @AliFELLAHI Yes, you can use that as long as you don't try to `await` it.