# Error when filtering a List with data that came from json data, the method where was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am new to Flutter , I have started an app that call the players and then filters the players by their role(Attacker, Midfielder, Defender, Goalkeeper) and i have faced a problem when i launched the application , the error says SplayerLab is null
the method where was called on null
Here what i have tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fantazy/controller/player_lab.dart';
import 'package:fantazy/model/player.dart';
import 'package:fantazy/create_team_view.dart';

class PlayersCreationDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Player> selectedPlayers;
  final int playerIndex;

  const PlayersCreationDetailsView ({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedPlayers,
    @required this.playerIndex
  })  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState createState() => _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState();
}

class _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState extends State<PlayersCreationDetailsView> {
  bool _sortAsc = false;
  int _sortColumnIndex = 0;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  PlayersDataSource _playersDataSource;
  List<Player> _players;

  int _rowsPerPage = 20;

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Player p), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _playersDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAsc = ascending ;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    List<Player> players = PlayerLab.get().players;
    //filter out players by position
    if (widget.playerIndex < 2) {
      _players = List<Player>.from(players.where((player) => player.position=="GK"));
    } else if (widget.playerIndex < 7) {
      _players = List<Player>.from(players.where((player) => player.position=="DEF"));
    } else if (widget.playerIndex < 12) {
      _players = List<Player>.from(players.where((player) => player.position=="MID"));
    } else {
      _players = List<Player>.from(players.where((player) => player.position=="FWD"));
    }
    //filter out players who are already selected
    for (Player player in widget.selectedPlayers) {
      _players.remove(player);
    }
    _playersDataSource = PlayersDataSource(widget.playerIndex, widget.selectedPlayers, _players, context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PaginatedDataTable(
              columnSpacing: 1.0,
              horizontalMargin: 1.0,
              availableRowsPerPage: [10,20,50],
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) { setState(() { _rowsPerPage = value; }); },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAsc,
              header: Text("Players"),
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnNameWidth , child: Text("First Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Player p) => p.firstName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnNameWidth , child: Text("Last Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Player p) => p.lastName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Position")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Player p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Price")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.price, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Team")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.team, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.points, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Week Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.pointsWeek, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
              /*  new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.appearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Sub Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.subAppearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Goals")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.goals, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Assists")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.assists, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
               
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Yellows")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.yellowCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Reds")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.redCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               
              ],
              source: _playersDataSource,
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class PlayersDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  PlayersDataSource(this._playerIndex, this._selectedPlayers, this._players, this.context);

  int _playerIndex;
  List<Player> _players;
  List<Player> _selectedPlayers;

  int _selectedCount = 0;
  var context;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Player p), bool ascending) {
    _players.sort((Player a, Player b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Player c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DataCell getCell(String text) {
    return DataCell(Container(width: _columnWidth, child: Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false,)));
  }

  


  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _players.length)
      return null;
    final Player player = _players[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      onSelectChanged: (bool) {
        _players.removeAt(index);
        _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {return CreateTeamView(players: _players, selectedPlayers: _selectedPlayers,);}));
      },
        index: index,
        cells: <DataCell>[
          getCell(player.firstName),
          getCell(player.lastName),
          getCell(player.position),
          getCell('${player.price}'),
         // getCell('${player.isFresher}'),
          getCell('${player.team}'),
          //getCell('${player.points}'),
         // getCell('${player.pointsWeek}'),
          getCell('${player.appearances}'),
         // getCell('${player.subAppearances}'),
          getCell('${player.goals}'),
          getCell('${player.assists}'),
          getCell('${player.cleanSheets}'),
         // getCell('${player.motms}'),
          getCell('${player.yellowCards}'),
          getCell('${player.redCards}'),
        //  getCell('${player.ownGoals}'),
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _players.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;


}
```

[image]

[image]

I am trying to fix the error and filter the list of players by their roles

Here my PlayerLab model:

```
import 'package:flutter_auth/Fantazyy/player%20copy.dart';

class PlayerLab {
  List<Playerr> _players = List();
  static PlayerLab _sPlayerLab;

  static PlayerLab get() {
    if (_sPlayerLab == null) {
      throw "sPlayerLab is null";
    }
    return _sPlayerLab;
  }

  void addPlayer(Playerr player) {
    _sPlayerLab.players.add(player);
  }

  Playerr getPlayer(int id) {
    for (Playerr player in _players) {
      if (player.playerID == id) {
        return player;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  PlayerLab();

  PlayerLab.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    _sPlayerLab = PlayerLab();
    for (Map<String, dynamic> playerJson in json) {
        addPlayer(Playerr.fromJson(playerJson));
      }
  }

  List<Playerr> get players => _players;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "where was called on null" implies, that players are null by the time you call it. I am assuming `PlayerLab.get().players` returns a Future so you should add the "await" keyword before the call:

```
initState() async {
   List<Player> players = await PlayerLab.get().players
   ....

  }
```

Comment: when i added await, i had an error , await is a type which is not a future, and also all the lines became red after i added await

Comment: You also need to add "async" to the ```initState``` method.  If that doesn't work, what is the returntype of the ```PlayerLab.get()``` method?

Comment: i have updated my answer , i added the code of PlayerLab model where the get method exists

Comment: `async` and `await` in `initState` is problematic.  This answer explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61764989/2301224.  It's fine to call async methods inside `initState`, just don't `await` them.

Comment: i have tried , but the problem that i mentionned on the top of the topic still exists

Comment: In your Player lab class, try this ```List<Playerr> _players = [] ```

Comment: Where do you get the players from ? What is playerLab ? If it is from a Database or any kind of source, other than data that exists during runtime, you should make sure to await the response of that source before you process the data.

Comment: i faced the problem of the empty _players , but now i face another type of problem : after i select a player i have a new error