# "await" in Widget build FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, async-await, build

I've been stuck for several hours with a problem on flutter. If you can help me that would be really nice.

I need to put "await" in my Widget build(BuildContext context){} but it's impossible to put "async".
How to do ?

[image]

When i test void _myAsyncMethod()async{} :
[image]

Comment: you can't make `build` asynchronous, use `initState`, create another  asynchronous method  inside there. More about [async](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). Another aproach will be using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I just tried to do with FutureBuilder but nothing worked...

Comment: which firebase_auth version you using

Comment: firebase_auth: "^0.10.0"

Comment: What you need is a `FutureBuilder`. Please add your code as plain text, so that its will be more search friendly.

Comment: in your second image `_myasyncmethod()` it will work asynchronously. so may rendering  widget first then complete the  `_myasyncmethod()`.what is `likes` property.where instatantiated?

Comment: @AlexleGoff if you found any answer below which resolved your issue then please mark as answered otherwise I'd suggest you to please write on how you find the solution to help the community

Comment: hi, no nothing helped me. I recommended my application from 0 to work around the problem

Answer (score 3):

To Fix your issue you can put **async** in the body of method like this

```
Before=> Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   

After=> Widget build(BuildContext context) async{
```

Although this will not solve your problem as flutter wiill warn you as this is not the proper way to do it.

It's not a good practice to call await inside flutter's build method Because

1. Generally an apps need to run a 60 frames per second on an average hence flutter's **build** method we'll be called over and over to re-render the ui.
2. Another reason is that, doing calling **await function()** in build method will block your UI.

**Solution**

1. use FutureBuilder
2. call await auth.currentUser() in initState method

Another way to solve this is to use **[FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)**

sample Code for 1

```
FutureBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<userModel> snapshot) {
        if(ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.userId);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
      future: auth.currentUser(),
    );
```

sample Code for 2(stateful widget)

```
late UserModel;   
void initState() {
 UserModel user = await auth.currentUser();   
}
```

this is very basic code but it's enough for you to get started.

**Note:** I've assumed `userModel` mentioned above is response type of `auth.currentUser()` you can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not optimal but you can create a method and put your `await` variable in there:

```
 late final FirebaseUser _user;
  void _myAsyncMethod()async{
    _user = await auth.currentUser;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _myAsyncMethod();
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(), body: Container());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If your are using *stateful* widget you can instantiate firebase auth in `initstate()` method.

```dart
class testFirless extends StatefulWidget {
  var currentuseid = "";

  testFirless({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _testFirlessState createState() => _testFirlessState();
}
class _testFirlessState extends State<testFirless> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  // ------------------------------------>heree
  @override
  Future<void> initState() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    var user = await auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      widget.currentuseid = user!.uid;
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  }
}
```

2. FutureBuilder

```dart
class fbuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const fbauth({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


// --------------->
    return Container(child: FutureBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        if (ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.userId.toString());
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
      future: auth.currentUser(),
    ));
  }
}
```

3. in `stateless` or `stateful` widget

```dart
String currentuseid="";
        class fbauth extends StatelessWidget {
          const fbauth({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         
       FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 //   ------------------------>    
            auth.currentUser().then((user) {
              if (user == null) {
                currentuseid = user!.uid;
              } else {
                print('User is signed in!');
              }
              // other logic after the user retrieval
            });
        
            return Container();
          }
}

Nb: Instead of instantiating firebase auth in every widget .you must instantiate in `void main` method
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It's super interesting but I still have a small error :/ -->    error: Undefined name 'currentuseid'.

Comment: just instatiate `currentuseid` or `currentuserid` outside the class.like the 3rd method i mention above.`String currentuseid="";`

Comment: I'm getting: `State.initState() must be a void method without an async keyword.` error. Solved it by moving the logic in another async function, which is then getting called in the initState, but without awaiting it. Until the user presses the first button, the async action is definitely finished. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61764989/12320109