# Flutter - Cannot modify List<Widget>

Tags: list, flutter, widget

I have a fixed-length List that is used in the "build" function. I want to replace one element in that List with another. Both elements in the List are Containers. I replace the element in the List and do a setState(). The build function uses the List in the body of the Scaffold. I get no error, however when the rebuild is done, nothing has changed.

To my knowledge this is not breaking any rules and as far as I know should cause no problems.

While I could code around the issue, I think that with something as fundamental as this, I need to find the reason for it.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Code added below:

### Below is the code that DOES NOT work

```
    if (_lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay] == null) /*INITIAL DISPLAY */ {
    _lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay] = wContainer;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _tfDataHasChanged = true;
        _lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay] = wContainer;
      });
    }
```

### Below is the code that DOES work

```
  if (_lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay] == null) /*INITIAL DISPLAY */ {
      _lwDisplay[iNdxDisplay] = wContainer;
    } else {
       _tfDataHasChanged = _fnHasDataChanged() /* FOR FAB */;
      List<Widget> lwDisplay2 = List(_lwDisplay.length);
      for (int iNdx = 0; iNdx < lwDisplay2.length; iNdx++) {
        if (iNdx != iNdxDisplay) {
          lwDisplay2[iNdx] = _lwDisplay[iNdx];
        }
      }
      lwDisplay2[iNdxDisplay] = wContainer;
      _lwDisplay = lwDisplay2;
      setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code with us so we can see what you are actually doing?

Comment: Have added code to my question.

Comment: posting source code that all defined in one single main.dart would be great for any one to help you easily. Also add expected and actual output.

Comment: @BrianOh - where have you created your list of widgets in your program?

Comment: @tomerpacific - I have created the widgets after the first build in a function called by onBuildComplete, IE after the first build. The program in question is fairly large, because I need to replicate a problem I am experiencing in another program that is part of an app, and to do that, I need to emulate that program as closely as possible.

Comment: @Darish - I would do that Darish, but, the program is a test program to emulate a program that is part of an app. To create a test environment, I have created this as closely as possible to the original program. I will try what you say, and if I can replicate it in something more manageable, I will do so. I'll try it with something more simple and see if I get the same result. The test program and related components is fairly large.

Comment: @BrianOh kindly prepare that sample code, otherwise it is almost impossible to guess what went wrong.

Comment: if it is a large main.dart file, you may post it as a gist on github.com and share the link.

Comment: @Darish - OK, I'll try a smaller program first, but I suspect it may be particular circumstances that cause it to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the entirety of code, and according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844804/flutter-setstate-not-updating-inner-stateful-widget),

Move the instantiation of the list of widgets to the build method of your main widget.

I.E.

```
class MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
      List<YOUR_WIDGET> _lwDisplay = new List();

     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          //Create your list
     }
}
```

Also, [add a key](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro#keys) to each item in your widget (if you haven't done so already).

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out asap, so I'll get back to you here.

Comment: I have spent quite a lot of time attempting to solve this, and thanks for your help. I did create another smaller test program to replicate the problem, but it worked without any problems. I did what you suggested regarding creation in the build, and using a key, but the program still malfunctioned. In the end, what I have just done, is in the build I create another List<Widget> as a local variable, and copy the global List<Widget> over element to it. This local List<Widget> is then used by the build and then discarded. That works.

Comment: @BrianOh - glad to hear things worked out. If my answer helped in any way, please mark it (or upvote).

Comment: OK, I up-voted because it shows me I need to learn about Widget Keys.