# How do I update a widget UI on button press then execute a function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, setstate

When a widget icon button is pressed, I want to change the button's icon, have setState rebuild the widget so the changed button icon is visible, then run a function:

```
bool _showPauseIcon = false;

void doSomething() {
 print("doSomething()");
}

.
.
.

IconButton(
 icon: _showPauseIcon ? Icon(Icons.pause) : Icon(Icons.play),
 onPressed:  () {
    _showPauseIcon = true;
    setState (() { });
    doSomething();
 },
)
```

doSomething() appears to be called before setState rebuilds the widget, so the modified icon only appears after doSomething() has been called - I need it to happen before doSomething() is called. I looking for the simplest possible solution.

Comment: Why is _showPauseIcon and doSomething not in the setState function? You should put those in setState

Comment: If I put _showPauseIcon and the call to doSomething() inside the setState function, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: are these built in the build method tree? Could you show the entire code

Comment: please show the entire code, also what you want exactly provide via image or gif file

Comment: I've read the notes on adding code to stack overflow comments, but can't get it to work yet...


It doesn't appear to matter whether the code is inside or outside the setState function. It's easy to prove that setState is being called asyncronously by Flutter by adding 

`Future<void> executeAfterBuild() async {
   print("executeAfterBuild()");
}`

before the widget build function. And inside the widget build function:

`  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    executeAfterBuild();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844804/flutter-setstate-not-updating-inner-stateful-widget check out this question and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SetState is only for the updating the widget on Current page.. So no need to call function inside the setstate.

```
IconButton(
 icon: _showPauseIcon ? Icon(Icons.pause) : Icon(Icons.play),
 onPressed:  () {
    setState (() {
_showPauseIcon = true;
 });
    doSomething();
 },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
onPressed: () {
        
    setState(() {
       _showPauseIcon = true;
    });
        
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {  
        doSomething();
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Some further background info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555999/flutter-setstate-doesnt-execute-until-the-enclosing-function-returns