# Flutter: when move to new page shared_prefernce from some reason stop working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

When back to BlueSettings page, initState show null on "Current value:"

When use stand alone BlueSettings whithout any MaterialPageRoute, it works

I want to use with MaterialPageRoute, what I do I miss?

Thanks for your help

here is my code:

---

**main.dart**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Application'),
      ),
      drawer: const DrawerMenu(),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**drawer_menu.dart**

```
class DrawerMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: const Text("Blue settings"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const BlueSettings(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**blue_settings.dart**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

okay I tried properly with simulator.

change setState to this:

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
      getValue("blueUri").then((value) => {
        _blueUriInit = value,
      });
    }));
```

Comment: Did not help, sorry

Comment: I have figured my problem, but I cannot understand why?

 Future<String> getValue(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String value = prefs.getString(key) ?? "NULL";
    return value;
}
always return NULL

Comment: refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844804/flutter-setstate-not-updating-inner-stateful-widget/63307118#63307118 basically pure setState is called before the widget is built, so the value doesn't appear in the widget even though it is actually loaded